# How to improve the performance of create a table using c plus plus API in DolphinDB

Tags: c++, database, dolphindb

I am using DolphinDB's c++ API to test the performance of writing to the database, and find that the performance of the generated data is relatively poor. Is there any way to improve it? My code is shown as bellow,

```
TableSP createDemoTable(long rows){
vector<string> colNames = {"fwname","filename","source_address","source_port","destination_address","destination_port","nat_source_address","nat_source_port","starttime","stoptime","elapsed_time"};
vector<DATA_TYPE> colTypes = {DT_SYMBOL,DT_STRING,DT_LONG,DT_LONG,DT_LONG,DT_LONG,DT_LONG,DT_LONG,DT_DATETIME,DT_DATETIME,DT_LONG};
int colNum = 11,rowNum = rows,indexCapacity=rows;
ConstantSP table = Util::createTable(colNames,colTypes,rowNum,indexCapacity);
vector<VectorSP> columnVecs;
for(int i = 0 ;i < colNum ;i ++)
    columnVecs.push_back(table->getColumn(i));

for(unsigned int i =  0 ;i < rowNum; i++){
    columnVecs[0]->set(i,Util::createString("10.189.45.2:9000"));
    columnVecs[1]->set(i,Util::createString("FWLOG_IOT22502_20190827110710_0000.DAT"));
    columnVecs[2]->set(i,Util::createLong(10*i));
    columnVecs[3]->set(i,Util::createLong(1*i));
    columnVecs[4]->set(i,Util::createLong(20*i));
    columnVecs[5]->set(i,Util::createLong(2*i));
    columnVecs[6]->set(i,Util::createLong(30*i));
    columnVecs[7]->set(i,Util::createLong(3*i));
    columnVecs[8]->set(i,Util::createDateTime(i+1568622660));
    columnVecs[9]->set(i,Util::createDateTime(i+1568622660+100));
    columnVecs[10]->set(i,Util::createLong(100));
}
return table;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your script, functions like `createString`, `createLong` are quite time-consuming. Besides, calling functions like `setInt`,`setLong` to append multiple rows of data in bulk instead of appending data row by row can improve performance significantly. You can refer to the examples in this [tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/api-cplusplus/blob/master/README_CN.md). Here's one of the examples which I think may help.

```
TableSP createDemoTable(){
    vector<string> colNames = {"name", "date", "price"};
    vector<DATA_TYPE> colTypes = {DT_STRING, DT_DATE, DT_DOUBLE};
    int colNum = 3, rowNum = 10000, indexCapacity=10000;
    ConstantSP table = Util::createTable(colNames, colTypes, rowNum, indexCapacity);
    vector<VectorSP> columnVecs;
    for(int i = 0; i < colNum; ++i)
        columnVecs.push_back(table->getColumn(i));

    int array_dt_buf[Util::BUF_SIZE]; //定义date列缓冲区数组
    double array_db_buf[Util::BUF_SIZE]; //定义price列缓冲区数组

    int start = 0;
    int no=0;
    while (start < rowNum) {
        size_t len = std::min(Util::BUF_SIZE, rowNum - start);
        int *dtp = columnVecs[1]->getIntBuffer(start, len, array_dt_buf); //dtp指向每次通过`getIntBuffer`得到的缓冲区的头部
        double *dbp = columnVecs[2]->getDoubleBuffer(start, len, array_db_buf); //dbp指向每次通过`getDoubleBuffer`得到的缓冲区的头部
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            columnVecs[0]->setString(i+start, "name_"+std::to_string(++no)); //对string类型的name列直接进行赋值，不采用getbuffer的方式
            dtp[i] = 17898+i; 
            dbp[i] = (rand()%100)/3.0;
        }
        columnVecs[1]->setInt(start, len, dtp); //写完后使用`setInt`将缓冲区写回数组
        columnVecs[2]->setDouble(start, len, dbp); //写完后使用`setDouble`将缓冲区写回数组
        start += len;
    }
    return table;
}
```